# COMO DAR ESTADO A CAMPOS VACÍOS

Tags: javascript, sql, qlikview

tengo el siguiente problema necesito asignar estado a facturas de pago las cuales son las siguientes si la deuda es igual a 0, pagado. Si la deuda es >0,'Adeudado'. Pero existen ciertos campos que están vacíos y no poseen dato lo cual he revisado si son Num('FACTURAS'), 'T','F' o text('FACTURAS'),'T','F' y me arroja falso mi código hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
------------------
If( Total deuda = 0, 'pagado',
if( Total deuda >0, 'Adeudado',
if( Total deuda = '-', 'Sin información'
-------------------
```

para el ultimo if no me trae ningún tipo de dato por ende no se puede completar el estado de 'Sin info'

Quedo atento a sus respuestas de antemano muchas gracias.
Saludos!.

Comment: Como puedo ''controlarlo'', si no logró traer nada no puedo asignarle a ese nada el valor default porque no consigo ningún dato, tienes alguna función de referencia que logré cumplir tomar el dato vacío?

Comment: Este dato proviene de un servidor por ello no lo puedo compartir...

Comment: Si la query esta dentro...

Comment: El valor de `total deuda` te devuelve el servidor?

Comment: No, eso lo realizo con un programa ,extraigo la query realizo los desarrollos y luego la vuelvo a cargar al servidor

Comment: Cómo asignas `-` cuando es `null`? O por qué no usas `-1`?

Comment: La query la tengo ya que trabajo con ella la extraigo para hacer los desarrollos y luego la vuelvo a cargar con los cambios realizados en los desarrollos

Comment: intente también para saber su formato con if(Num(campo), 'T','F' tambien con if(text(campo), 'T', 'F' me arroja F  en ambas y también con if(Len(Trim(N DOCTO) >0, 'sin ingresar' y tampoco trae dato

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar

```
pick(match(alt([Total deuda],-1),0,-1)+1,'Adeudado', 'Pagado','Sin información')
```

Básicamente lo que hace el alt es dejar el valor salvo que sea `null` donde le asigna -1, luego el match compara el valor de [Total deuda], y le asigna la cardinalidad, si no existe devuelve 0 , por eso se usa el +1, así luego el pick devuelve el valor según el orden, por eso para todos los positivos devuelve Adeudado.